# Get image URL from bootstrap modal to java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I am modifying one image and show it in a modal, but I am not getting the image URL because this image modified and show in bootstrap modal.
I want to get URL for this image in JavaScript for upload to server.

> I have already seen this link but am not satisfied this solution:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754900](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754900/how-to-load-image-into-bootstrap-modal-with-javascript)

[image]

HTML CODE:

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     <a class="btn btn-primary" id="upload" download="cropped.png" href="javascript:void(0);">Upload</a>
 </div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
        $('#upload').click(function () {
                        var b = result.toDataURL();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/sf/p/customizeText",
                            type: 'GET',
                            data: b,
                            success: function (response) {

                            },
                            complete: function (response) {

                            },
                            error: function (response) {

                            }
                        });
                    });
```

I want to send this cropped image URL to server, but i am not getting
 URL from this image because cropped image will be new each time and it
 is temporary save in browser after reload image is lose.
 I am save this image in variable b, But this is in bas64 form, we can directly send to /sf/p/customizeText (url) by ajax?

> Can we assign result.toDataURL() in varaible b and pass in ajax Like
>
> ```
>                             data: b,
> ```

Please give me some idea for achieve this solution.

Comment: Create a fiddle for your code.

Comment: I am not able to create fiddle because code is so lengthy and dependent on many files. But modal code this one only. thanks Adam

Answer (score 2):

The image cropped will most likely be a **base64** encoded image. You should post the HTML of the image tag. You can get the image sorurce via `attr()`.

```
var imageSrc = $('#id').attr('src'); //data%3Aimage%2Fpng%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE
```

You have to get the `src` of the image tag via js and send it to the server. Then you can either **save the string and use it directly** as image or **decode** it. I give you a little example on how to do that with PHP and Java.

**PHP**

```
//save your data into a variable - last part is the base64 encoded image
$encoded = "data%3Aimage%2Fpng%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE";
//decode the url, because we want to use normal charackters to use explode
$decoded = urldecode($encoded);
//explode at ',' - the last part should be the encoded image now
$exp = explode(',', $decoded);
//we just get the last element with array_pop
$base64 = array_pop($exp);
//decode the image and finally save it
$data = base64_decode($base64);
$file = 'data.png';
//make sure you are the owner and have the rights to write content
file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

**Java**

```
byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64(crntImage);
try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("c:/decode/abc.bmp")) {
    stream.write(data);
}
```

Comment: This is good but i am working with java. And i cant assign image into file in java script. I want url for this modal image in java script.

Comment: you need to get the the source via jqueries attr(). you can write it to a file then on server side with java too.